# can we pass $_POST value by clicking link?

Tags: php, api, post

I need to build some php API to upload an image cross subdomain.

Example, upload script located at http://sub.domain.com/upload.php

and I neew to upload an image to http://www.domain.com/media/

I read some content at http://www.v-nessa.net/2009/02/09/simple-api-writing-part-i and i suspect that can we pass $_POST value by clicking link? How?

Comment: By using javascript `onClick="document.formname.submit();"`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that... by submitting a form while clicking that link

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.myformname.submit();">Submit</a>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because you asked it :) Although no one says that :)

Comment: @Sarfraz.... I dont mean to be rude, but its better if we don't crowd a post with similar answers. Hope you are not offended though... :D

Comment: I am not at all, I should have deleted my post initially on if i had seen yours :)